# SVN branch to trunk merge doesn't work, only shows "property changes", not code changes

Tags: svn, version-control

I have svn 1.6.11 and I am trying to merge mybranch onto the trunk. I have tried both

```
svn merge --reintegrate http://IP/path/to/repo/branches/mybranch http://IP/path/to/repo/trunk 

svn ci -m "blah"
```

and

```
svn merge http://IP/path/to/repo/branches/mybranch http://IP/path/to/repo/trunk 

svn ci -m "blah"
```

They both gave me after the merge:

```
$ svn diff

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /repo/trunk:r23
```

and after the commit:

```
Sending        trunk
```

I do not see the changes in the trunk.  When I diff the trunk version before the merge (18) to the latest version (24), I get:

```
$ svn diff -r 18:24

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /repo/trunk:r20-23
```

I don't just want property changes. I want the code changes to be merged. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The command line looks weird, because you are using two URLs. Create a clean working copy of the trunk and try `svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/mybranch`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: I agree with @nosid - don't try to perform a server-side merge. Checkout the target of your merge (`trunk`) and perform the merge on your local copy.

Comment: I think that was my problem!!! I was trying into merge into the trunk at the server-side, not realizing that I should perform the merge on my local copy first! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure all your changes are committed on the branch, in your development directory `svn commit -m "etc commits"`
2. Merge all changes in the trunk into your branch, *I personally would test at this point*, and recommit on the branch at this point. `svn merge http://IP/path/to/repo/trunk .`, ***testing***, `svn commit -m "Merged from trunk and passed tests`
3. Check out the trunk - `svn co http://IP/path/to/repo/trunk`
4. Merge from your branch into the trunk in your Working Copy of trunk `svn merge --reintegrate http://IP/path/to/repo/branches/mybranch .`
5. **TESTING**, *more testing*, ***yet more testing!!***!
6. Commit back on to trunk: `svn commit -m"My Feature Merged In"`
7. Get ready for the bug reports for the problems that **all** your tests missed.

**N.B.** The SVN documentation mentions 2 URL or server side merges - mostly to *"say this is possible but difficult so don't even try it unless your **really** know what you are doing"*

Comment: For reintegration, it is **a must** pre-merge trunk to branch

Comment: step 3a *can be* `svn diff URL/OF/BRANCH URL/OF/TRUNK` in order to see content-difference

Comment: @LazyBadger Re 2 - I agree & will change it, re 3a I would say that is a user preference _but_ you will still need to check out the trunk eventually and 2 will probably have resulted in you looking at the differences while resolving any conflicts.

Comment: I followed everything and it worked (thanks!), except for step 3. I did NOT "Check out the trunk - snv co http://IP/path/to/repo/trunk" Instead, I just changed my directory from the branch to the trunk directory.

Comment: Ah @HaoQiLi we get to a part of your problem - You have checked out `http://IP/path/to/repo/` rather than `http://IP/path/to/repo/trunk` and/or `http://IP/path/to/repo/branches/somebranch` - I always strongly recommend not to do this.  You are wasting a huge amount of disc space and setting yourself up for problems.  If you need to be working on trunk and a branch at once - not uncommon - then have two completely separate check outs in two separate directories.  One of the common mistakes when working at the level above is using copy to create a new branch - so no history!